# How can I start the secondary core in Jetson TK1(arm a15)

Tags: arm

I'm a student form China, and I'm trying to port a OS(Barrelfish) to Jetson TK1.
Now I had make the primary core working.

But when I start to deal with the secondary core, there are problems.

first, I just know using the "SEV" instruction can wake up a core (in WFE or WFI). I don't know what else i have to do?

**Most important thing is I don't know how to set the secondary core's boot address.**

I tried to find answer from the linux code for Jetson TK1, but I didn't find any code setting the address.

Can you tell me want i should to do?

Comment: I've not touched a Tegra myself, but I highly doubt the secondary cores would be online and sat executing a WFE loop in the bootloader - they're almost certainly going to need powering up and releasing from reset. If you're lucky there might be some firmware you can call to do the job for you; if you're unlucky it's going to entail whatever complicated dance of poking power controllers etc. that that particular SoC demands. From a quick look at arch/arm/mach-tegra/platsmp.c in mainline Linux, I suspect you may well be unlucky...

Comment: I assume each core has a separate reset and enable.  but if you look at the raspberry pi for example they release them all at once and early boot software has to sort them out.   It is an outside the arm core thing though so it is chip specific and you need to find chip docs.   I assume the secondary cores also start at zero like the primary, that should be in the arm docs.

Answer (score 0):

I have got it by myself. thanks everybody who take care of this question.

In the jetson tk1 TRM， I just found that cpu fetches code from reset-vector register(in EVP register)[TRM 15.1.6.2], and the description of EVP is so simple. as follow:

[EVP register](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qdNs2.png)

and this:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tD15y.png)

so I tried to write the boot address to the 0x00000000, but it made no effect.

finally, I had to try to dump memory using u-boot(md 0x0 100).

I found a useful value(0x83d8e000, the load address of u-boot) in 0x400 and 0x500 ... (from 0x400 to 0x1400)

so I tried to write the boot address of barrelfish to memory(all bytes of 0x400-0x1400), the secondary core worked!

then I tried to found the true register for secondary core, and it's **0x500**.

By the way, the code to the boot secondary core is from linux.

It's all, my English is poor. if there are any errors in my words, just  forgive me.